Gutenberg page templates
I am trying to add a block to my page template, specifically a core/cover. Ideally I'd like to make sure the tag for the text in the cover is an H1, and a base colour already chosen as the background. Does anyone know if that is possible? I am having a hard time finding any documentation for achieving this. I know I can just write my own custom block, but I would love to just use the core. I have found the following which have helped a little but left me searching for more documentation.
Page Templates
Mapping Fields
Nested Blocks (comment)
